# Rails 4 model attribute not settable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In Rails 4 I have a message model with a relationship to `user` and `template`. It also has it's own attribute , `text`.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :text

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :template

validates :user, presence: true
validates :template, presence: true
validates :text, presence: true, if: lambda { |message| message.template.present? }

    def initialize(args = {})
      super
      @user = args[:user]
      @template = args[:template]
      @text = args[:text] || (args[:template].text if args[:template].present?)
    end

end
```

Here is my problem:
(assume I have a `user` and `template` already)
When I run `message = Message.create!(user: user, template: template, "hello world")`
`message.text` will equal `"hello world"`, but when I retrieve this record from he database, it's `text` attribute is `nil`, and all other attributes are OK.

What gives? Why is `text` not being persisted to the database?

Comment: Why are you using attr_accessor :text ? In that way you are "overwriting" ActiveRecord text attribute and all it's behaviours, that's probably why it's not written to the db. Also be careful, text may be a reserved word (db type `text`)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no reason given the code you've provided why you should be overriding the `ActiveRecord::Base.initialize` method. This is generally bad practice. The setter on `@user` and `@template` is not necessary at all; Rails will set the model attributes for you through the base initialize method.
2. The default functionality you have for the `@text` setter should be provided in an `after_initialize` block

   ```
   after_initialize do
     self.text = self.template if self.text.blank? && self.template.present?
   end
   ```
3. If `:text` is truly a model attribute *(matches a column in the database)*, you should not be calling `attr_accessor :text` on your `Message` model. It will do you no good, and overwrites `ActiveRecord::Base` functionality for `text` and `text=` methods.